# Relabel Year Month Variable To Inform Proc Freq Order

Tags: sas

I have a date time variable 'chg_date_of_svc' and would like to make this variable a month_year variable. To do this, I simply wrote the follow code:

```
 data combined1;
 set combined;
 MONTH_YEAR=chg_date_of_svc;
 format MONTH_YEAR monyy7.;
 run;
```

I would then like to use the month_year variable in a proc freq statement; however, the month_years do not appear in chronological order when using the following code. For example, January 2019 appears before December 2018 in the tables the proc freq statement produces.

This may not be the easiest solution but I suspect I have to relabel the specific year_months so they appear in the the correct chronological order?

```
 proc freq data = combined1 order=data;
 table EM_Charge*MONTH_YEAR;
 run;
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If the variable has datetime values why are you use a date format instead of a datetime format like `dtmonyy.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requested that it list of columns in the order that they first appear in the input dataset.  If you want them in chronological order then remove the `ORDER=DATA` option.  If you must use ORDER=DATA then sort the data first.